# Rinkeby authenticated Faucet is saying "insufficient funds for gas*price + value"

Tags: rinkeby, ethereum-classic

[image: In this image I did the following steps to test Ethereum and it shows this msg.]

I am learning more about the blockchain so I just started a tutorial on Freecodecamp, in the following video I need to test Ethereum from Rinkeby authenticated Faucet, I did the following step but showed an error.
can anyone help?

Comment: Rinkeby Deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's showing an error because Rinkeby Testnet is almost deprecated. Check this [warning](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/).
Migrate your contracts and deploy new ones on Goerli or Sepolia. The only two testnets, developers will maintain after the merge.

Use Goerli from now on, It is the most recommended testnet rn.
Goerli Testnet Faucet: https://goerlifaucet.com/

Comment: BTW I don't think that Rinkeby is deprecated fully. So as you said you are new, you can try to get some Rinkeby ETHs from here https://faucets.chain.link/rinkeby . Rinkeby authenticated Faucet has some of his own issues/bugs I think. It's showing me the same thing for the Gorli testnet ETHs request. So try Chainlink Rinkeby Faucet

Answer (score 0):

FYI Goerli is officially the only Ethereum testnet, Rinkeby and all other testnets are deprecated. +1 for https://goerlifaucet.com